# NullPointerException reading line from file

Tags: java

I have this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("hello.txt"));

        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine().trim()) != null) {
            if (line.startsWith("Hello")) {
                line = br.readLine().trim();
            } else {
                ... code ...
            }
        }

        br.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But once the file reaches the end, I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

On the line:

```
while ((line = br.readLine().trim()) != null) {
```

Why? How to fix it?

Comment: You're trimming before you check for `null`.  Do that in the other order.

Comment: Why do you think you shouldn't get a `NullPointerException`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following; ine which you are trying to read is null hence calling trim throws NPE;

```
while (br.readLine() != null)
        {
            line = br.readLine().trim()
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you try to read using `readLine()`

```
line = br.readLine().trim())
```

if `br.readLine()` return *null*, then calling  `trim()` cause NPE.

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    line.trim();                   
    if (line.startsWith("Hello")) {
        if ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            line.trim();
        }

    } else {

    }
}
```

Comment: The NPE isn't happening when trying to *read* `line`, it's when trying to assign a value to it from the reader.  Initializing it first won't do anything at all.

Comment: @azurefrog , sorry, I didn't noticed,  answer edited.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ((line = br.readLine().trim()) != null)
```

remove the `trim()`
and added it within the while loop.

```
line = line.trim();
```